# Make MATLAB slider NOT slide when arrow keys are pressed

Tags: matlab, user-interface, slider

I think this might be a simple question.

Basically, I have a (continuous) slider that I have implemented in MATLAB. If I click the slider and slide the tab, I get what I want, etc. That is good.

Now, the Up/Down/Left/Right arrow keys ALSO make the slider slide. However, I do not want to make the slider move, but I want to use them for something else. So, how can I stop the slider from moving the slide tab when the arrow keys are pressed, so that I can use them for something else?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you can see what key was pressed with the `eventdata` through `eventdata.Key`. If it's an up, down, left, or right key then you should just be able to issue a return to prevent the slider from doing anything.

Comment: @jucestain I do in fact have a listener for the eventData, yes. In fact it just displays "left", "right" etc for whatever button is pressed, but the slider thumb ALSO moves. What do you mean 'issue a return' to prevent the slider from doing anything? Thanks much.

Comment: Hmm... I was referring to the slider callback function. The return would prevent the slider callback from firing but the arrow keys might still move the slider. I tried overwriting the `KeyPressFcn` callback and that still doesn't work, so I'm not sure what you can do.

Comment: This is strange, I've overwritten all the keypress callbacks for the figure as well as the slider uicontrol and I can't seem to prevent slider from moving on an arrowkey press. Very strange. I'm using an old version of matlab so it's possible it was a bug that was fixed. Good luck.

Comment: @jucestain What version are you using? Right now it appears user2816823's answer is the best game in town, although it is somewhat hacky.

Comment: Its 2009. Maybe Ill try look at this again on a comp I have at work tomorrow that has 2013

Answer (score 1):

It`s doing this because when you click on the slider, the slider gets focus.

In your slider callback, at the very end of the call:

```
set(hObject, 'Enable', 'off');
drawnow;
set(hObject, 'Enable', 'on');
```

This will force the slider to lose focus. This is very much a hack but should work.

Comment: Hmm thanks, this does appear to work... for now... like you, I am concerned that it might give me problems later on since it is hacky... Perhaps there is another way as well?

Answer (score 0):

A different solution not invoking the (slow) drawnow function, since the slider callback seems to be called continuously with a key pressed when in focus, is to use java and request focus to a different component in the slider callback. Something like this (I'm shifting focus to an innocuous uipanel):
    jhUipanel = findjobj(hUipanel);
    jhUipanel.requestFocus;

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer here:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/33224-gui-figure-focus

```
jPeer = get(handle(gcf), 'JavaFrame');
jPeer.getAxisComponent.requestFocus;
```

The answer from Guest36 probably works too if you download Yair's findjobj function, but I didn't try that.